# Custom decode binary data in polars

Tags: python, binary, python-polars

when working with binary data, I am using custom function in order to decode them. This requires the usage of apply in polars. Due to the element wise processing in this case, the calculation time is increasing significantly, when working with larg data sets.

I tried to cast the binary data to List(UInt8), but this is not yet implemented.

```
exceptions.ArrowErrorException: NotYetImplemented("Casting from LargeBinary to LargeList(Field { name: \"item\", data_type: UInt8, is_nullable: true, metadata: {} }) not supported")
```

Is there a more efficiant way of doing it?

```
import polars as pl
import struct
import io

data = {"binary": [b'\xFD\x00\xFE\x00\xFF\x00',b'\x10\x00\x20\x00\x30\x00'], "id": [1,2]}
schema = {"binary": pl.Binary, "id":pl.Int16}

df = pl.DataFrame(data, schema)
```

This returns:

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌───────────────┬─────┐
│ binary        ┆ id  │
│ ---           ┆ --- │
│ binary        ┆ i16 │
╞═══════════════╪═════╡
│ [binary data] ┆ 1   │
│ [binary data] ┆ 2   │
└───────────────┴─────┘
```

Now when we apply our function to decode the binary column:

```
def custom_decode(data):
   bytestream = io.BytesIO(data)
   lst = []

   while bytestream.tell() < 6:
      lst.append(struct.unpack('<H', bytestream.read(2))[0])

   return lst

df = df.with_columns([
      pl.col('binary').apply(lambda x: custom_decode(x))
   ])
```

Result:

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────────────────┬─────┐
│ binary          ┆ id  │
│ ---             ┆ --- │
│ list[i64]       ┆ i16 │
╞═════════════════╪═════╡
│ [253, 254, 255] ┆ 1   │
│ [16, 32, 48]    ┆ 2   │
└─────────────────┴─────┘
```

Comment: I can see if I can add that cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added the cast upstream. In the next release of polars; `polars>=0.18.1`, you can do this:

```py
data = {"binary": [b'\xFD\x00\xFE\x00\xFF\x00',b'\x10\x00\x20\x00\x30\x00'], "id": [1,2]}
schema = {"binary": pl.Binary, "id":pl.Int16}

(
    pl.DataFrame(data, schema)
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("binary").cast(pl.List(pl.UInt8))
    )
)
```

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌───────────────┬─────┐
│ binary        ┆ id  │
│ ---           ┆ --- │
│ list[u8]      ┆ i16 │
╞═══════════════╪═════╡
│ [253, 0, … 0] ┆ 1   │
│ [16, 0, … 0]  ┆ 2   │
└───────────────┴─────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple ideas that might make marginal improvements.

1. instead of the while, use a list comprehension since you know you're doing that 3 times. The improvement here is that the list size will be allocated in advance instead of appending. Appending to lists is more expensive than starting with preallocated ones.
2. do the looping inside your custom function and have it return a Series so you can use map instead of apply (I'm not sure what the relative overhead of polars looping vs python looping is though)

You could write your function like this

```
def custom_decode(data):
    retL=[None] * len(data)
    for i, datum in enumerate(data):
        bytestream = io.BytesIO(datum)
        retL[i]=[struct.unpack('<H', bytestream.read(2))[0] for _ in range(3)]
    return(pl.Series(retL))
```

and then do

```
df.with_columns([
    pl.col('binary').map(custom_decode)
])
```