# Cast binary to any dtype in polars

Tags: python, python-polars

I am working with binary data and have to cast it into specific dtypes. In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76379674/custom-decode-binary-data-in-polars) casting from binary to list(u8) was made available. At the moment I am doing the cast for other dtypes as follows:

binary -> uint32

```
import polars as pl

data = {
    "test": [b'\x00\x0A\x0C\x10',b'\x00\x0A\x0C\x00']
}
schema = {
    "test": pl.Binary
}

df = pl.DataFrame(data, schema).with_row_count('id')

hex_dict = {
    "a": "10"
    ,"b": "11"
    ,"c": "12"
    ,"d": "13"
    ,"e": "14"
    ,"f": "15"
}

df = df.with_columns([
      pl.col('test')
    .bin.encode('hex')
    .str.split('')
    .list.slice(1,8)
   ]).explode('test').with_columns([
      pl.col('test').map_dict(hex_dict, default=pl.first()).cast(pl.Int8)
   ]).with_row_count().with_columns([
      ((pl.col('row_nr').mod(8).cast(pl.Int8)-7).abs()).alias('exp')
   ]).with_columns([
      (pl.col('test') * pl.lit(16).pow(pl.col('exp'))).alias('value')
   ]).groupby('id').agg([
    pl.col("value").sum().cast(pl.UInt32)
   ])
```

result:

```
┌─────┬────────┐
│ id  ┆ value  │
│ --- ┆ ---    │
│ u32 ┆ u32    │
╞═════╪════════╡
│ 0   ┆ 658448 │
│ 1   ┆ 658432 │
└─────┴────────┘
```

Basically the binary data is encoded in hex, split into a list and then the df is exploded. The alphanumeric values are mapped, the exponent is created and in the end we calculate the resulting value. -> n1* 16⁷ + n2* 16⁶ + n3* 16⁵ + ...

Then if I would like to do it for little endian then the ordering of the bytes would have to be reversed. How would I do it in polars for a given string:

```
hex = "FD00FE00"
hex-reversed = "00FE00FD"
```

**Question 1:**
We can split hex into ["F","D","0","0","F","E","0","0"] and then use list.reverse(), but we would need to split hex into ["FD","00","FE","00"] and then reverse. How this could be done?

So this is only for casting into integers and it is very cumbersome.

**Question 2:**
Will casting (binary->int8,..float64 ever be implemented in polars, or is it out of scope?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't use `polars`, but this would be *trivial* with `numpy`: `np.frombuffer(b''.join(data['test']), dtype=np.uint32).byteswap()`

Comment: or, using dtype string specifiers: `np.frombuffer(b''.join(data['test']), dtype='>u4')`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. Thanks for the suggestion. I will try it and take a look at the performance. In real world application, there are 10000+ of binary values each representing a list of floats with a length of 10000+.

Comment: Answering the first question: Using .str.extract_all(r".{2}") does the job well.

Answer (score 1):

Polars is happy to accept the numpy vector
that @juanpa.arrivillaga suggests:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import polars as pl
>>> 
>>> data = { "test": [b'\x00\x0A\x0C\x10',b'\x00\x0A\x0C\x00'] }
>>> 
>>> np.frombuffer(b''.join(data['test']), dtype='>u4')
array([658448, 658432], dtype=uint32)
>>> 
>>> pl.Series(list(np.frombuffer(b''.join(data['test']), dtype='>u4')), dtype=pl.UInt32)
shape: (2,)
Series: '' [u32]
[
    658448
    658432
]
```